# How do you convert a case class to a class?

Tags: json, scala, messagepack

I have a `case class` `Person(name:String, id:Int)` for serialization reasons (`MessagePack`), I need to convert this to a `class`. Is there an easy / elegant way to do this which does not require too much boilerplate or creation?

`case class Person(name:String, id:Int)` -> `class Person(name:String, id:Int)`

Comment: I don't understand.Case class is a class just with some extra methods which I think has no conflict with MessagePack.

Comment: There's quite a lot to it if you want the exact same functionality: implementing and maintaining `Person.apply`, `copy`, `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` and deriving from `Product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A case class can be serialized as a "normal" class as it is de facto a normal class.
As it makes all constructor arguments accessable by default it's an even better fit for serialisation than a normal class.

The **case class** just tells the compiler to automatically add some methods as *equals* and *hashCode* to the class. At the same time there is a **companion object** with an **apply** method added, but this doesn't affect the normal class at all.

So if there arise problems with Serialization the chance is quite hight that the source of the problem lies elsewhere.

You could try **json4s** https://github.com/json4s/json4s to convert your case class to JSON and then convert it to the MessagePack format.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}
implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(ShortTypeHints(List(classOf[Person])
val jsonString : String = write(Person("Andi", 42))

// convert with MessagePack as you would do with normal JSON
```